# How to send message to websocket connected user by a Servcie

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux

I have a client side app ( ReatJS ) which instantiates a webSocket connection with the server ( Spring Boot ) and waits to receive data.
At a certain moment the server has to send data to a specific user on the WebSocket channel, the call to the function that starts the sending is inside a class annotated with @Service

How do I send a message using WebFlux via WebSocket to a specific user? I identify the user by id or by his connection-id

These are some classes

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig {

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>(){{
            put("/data", new MyHandler());
        }};
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setUrlMap(map);
        mapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return mapping;
    }

}
```

```java
public class MyHandler implements WebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
        return webSocketSession.send( ... );
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    public void sendToUser(String userId, String connectionId, String message) {
        // send message to connected user through WebSocket
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to filter the connections by user id and send message to all your connections. It should work.

Comment: Ok I known it I need to filter connections, but how can I send the message? I simply call (new MyHandler()).handle() ? And from MyService where can I find all connections?